# Graphing syntax from Maple translating into Wolfram Alpha?

Tags: maple

[image]

The above image was generated using Maple software in both spherical and cartesian coordinates:

Spherical Coordinates:

plot3d([
sin(2*phi)*cos(2*theta),
theta, 
Phi],
theta=0..2*Pi, phi=0..Pi,
axes=BOXED, coords=spherical, grid=[80,80],lightmodel=light1)
http://www.maplesoft.com/applications/view.aspx?SID=4012&view=html

Cartesian Coordinates: (same figure)

plot3d([
rad*sin(theta)*sin(phi),
 rad*cos(theta)*sin(phi), 
rad*cos(phi)], 
theta=0..2*Pi, phi=0..Pi,axes=BOXED, grid=[40,40],lightmodel=light1);

How can this be graphed on Wolfram-Alpha?
I tried: 
[3D parametric plot [ { sin(2*phi)*cos(2*theta),  theta,  Phi }, {u,0,2*Pi},{v,0,2*Pi}]](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3D%20parametric%20plot%20%5B%20%7B%20sin(2*phi)*cos(2*theta),%20%20theta,%20%20Phi%20%7D,%20%7Bu,0,2*Pi%7D,%7Bv,0,2*Pi%7D%5D) and something is wrong. I think wolfram alpha doesn't realize this is meant to be spherical coordinates.

I tried using the "cartesian" equation from Maple in the same 3D Paramtric plot, and [here is what happened](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3D%20parametric%20plot%20%5B%20%7B%20rad*sin(theta)*sin(phi),%20%20rad*cos(theta)*sin(phi),%20%20rad*cos(phi)%20%7D,%20%7Bu,0,2*Pi%7D,%7Bv,0,2*Pi%7D%5D). I am not sure what rad is meant to be, but WA is interpreting it as radians.

Comment: Might be worth asking this on Mathematica.SE as Wolfram makes both and while the Mathematica command for such a graph doesn't appear to work on WA the experts over there might know how to get it to happen.

Comment: @IanMiller http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/125691/graphing-syntax-from-maple-translating-into-wolfram-alpha